# Lumen Enable CSRF Token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I know lumen is used to session less API development still i have a situation where i need to enable CSRF token.Session every think works fine but i need to enable csrf token if i add

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

in form i got error

> (1/1) ReflectionException Class
>   Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken does not exist

In bootstrap/app.php i have uncommented following

```
$app->middleware([
      'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
     'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
     'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
   'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
 ]);
```

even i have enabled

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'csrf' => 'Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'
]);
```

if i comment csrf in middleware then  i get following error

Call to undefined function csrf_token() in blade

I am using laravel `"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.5.*",`

can any one help me how i can enable VerifyCsrfToken in lumen

Comment: Does the class at least exist? Have you tried the typical "composer dump-autoload" ?

Comment: @Amarnasan.where it will be actually.even i searched for that fiel but didntf found

Comment: if it is ok you can use JWT for your requirement. it's bit easy to use with Lumen

Comment: @Pyramid.ya i agree but in this project i cant use

Comment: what is your current session driver ?

Comment: have you added in routes??

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi.i have file session

Comment: @Pyramid.no i have not added since my get login page throw eror for csrf token in blade

Comment: check this link I guess you need to add middleware in your route like mentioned in question https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/lumen-csrf-token-mismatch

Comment: Ya i checked that already

Comment: what if you run artisan config  clear

Comment: Did you cache your config after making changes?

Comment: no i cant rrun php artisan config:clear.there are no command erorr

Answer (score 4):

Had this same issue. Posting here if someone in future.

Found out that they removed all `csrf` stuff from lumen since 5.2 (not exactly sure since which version).  To use csrf in Lumen 5.5 or later you need to create yourself or copy `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware file from laravel package of that specific version (find in github) and place in lumen middleware folder and adjust the path in `bootstrap/app.php` accordingly.

You may need to install `illuminate/cookie` or other required package manually as well.

`VerifyCsrfToken.php` file can be found at `laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

Answer (score 1):

From the lumen documentation [Validation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)

> Form Requests
>
> Form requests are not supported by Lumen. If you would like to use form requests, you should use the full Laravel framework.

The Lumen microframework v5.8 don't support form, so it don't have csrf